glmer and 'hessian is numerically singular'
I have following dataframe:
> test_df
   sample pers expl resp
1       1    1    a    1
2       2    2    a    1
3       3    3    a    1
4       4    4    a    1
5       5    5    a    1
6       6    1    b    1
7       7    2    b    1
8       8    3    b    0
9       9    4    b    1
10     10    5    b    1
11     11    1    c    0
12     12    2    c    1
13     13    3    c    0
14     14    4    c    1
15     15    5    c    0
16     16    1    d    1
17     17    2    d    1
18     18    3    d    0
19     19    4    d    1
20     20    5    d    1
21     21    1    e    1
22     22    2    e    1
23     23    3    e    0
24     24    4    e    1
25     25    5    e    1
26     26    1    f    0
27     27    2    f    0
28     28    3    f    0
29     29    4    f    0
30     30    5    f    0
31     31    1    g    1
32     32    2    g    1
33     33    3    g    0
34     34    4    g    0
35     35    5    g    0
36     36    6    a    1
37     37    7    a    1
38     38    8    a    1
39     39    9    a    1
40     40   10    a    1
41     41    6    h    1
42     42    7    h    1
43     43    8    h    1
44     44    9    h    1
45     45   10    h    1
46     46    6    i    1
47     47    7    i    1
48     48    8    i    1
49     49    9    i    1
50     50   10    i    1
51     51    6    d    1
52     52    7    d    1
53     53    8    d    1
54     54    9    d    1
55     55   10    d    1
56     56    6   d2    1
57     57    7   d2    1
58     58    8   d2    1
59     59    9   d2    1
60     60    6    e    1
61     61    7    e    1
62     62    8    e    1
63     63    9    e    1
64     64   10    e    1
65     65    6   e2    1
66     66    7   e2    1
67     67    8   e2    1
68     68    9   e2    1
69     69   10   e2    1
70     70    6    g    1
71     71    7    g    0
72     72    8    g    1
73     73    9    g    1
74     74   10    g    0

And I want to test if there are any statistic significant differences. Response variable is 'resp', explanatory variable is 'expl' and random variable is 'pers'.
I apply following command:
model <- glmer(resp~expl+(1|pers), data=test_df, family=binomial)

But I get following warning message:
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined

I'm relatively new into modelling and I would like to know what is the problem here.
Thanks in advance.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/187841/163114

Jay's link gives a good answer, but I thought I might add some specifics.
# Here's your data, except I dropped the `sample` column, as it wasn't used.

tt <- structure(list(pers=structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
  5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 8L,
  9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 8L,
  9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), levels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
  "8", "9", "10"), class="factor"), expl=structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
  2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L,
  8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L,
  10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
  6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), levels=c("a", "b", "c", "d",
  "d2", "e", "e2", "f", "g", "h", "i"), class="factor"), resp=c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
  1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names=c(NA, -74L),
  class="data.frame")

If we run table() we'll get a good overview of your data.
table(tt)
# , , resp = 0
# 
#     expl
# pers a b c d d2 e e2 f g h i
#   1  0 0 1 0  0 0  0 1 0 0 0
#   2  0 0 0 0  0 0  0 1 0 0 0
#   3  0 1 1 1  0 1  0 1 1 0 0
#   4  0 0 0 0  0 0  0 1 1 0 0
#   5  0 0 1 0  0 0  0 1 1 0 0
#   6  0 0 0 0  0 0  0 0 0 0 0
#   7  0 0 0 0  0 0  0 0 1 0 0
#   8  0 0 0 0  0 0  0 0 0 0 0
#   9  0 0 0 0  0 0  0 0 0 0 0
#   10 0 0 0 0  0 0  0 0 1 0 0
# 
# , , resp = 1
# 
#     expl
# pers a b c d d2 e e2 f g h i
#   1  1 1 0 1  0 1  0 0 1 0 0
#   2  1 1 1 1  0 1  0 0 1 0 0
#   3  1 0 0 0  0 0  0 0 0 0 0
#   4  1 1 1 1  0 1  0 0 0 0 0
#   5  1 1 0 1  0 1  0 0 0 0 0
#   6  1 0 0 1  1 1  1 0 1 1 1
#   7  1 0 0 1  1 1  1 0 0 1 1
#   8  1 0 0 1  1 1  1 0 1 1 1
#   9  1 0 0 1  1 1  1 0 1 1 1
#   10 1 0 0 1  0 1  1 0 0 1 1
# 

As you can see it's very unbalanced (many more cases where resp = 1 than resp = 0) and sparse (many zeros in both tables, including some rows and columns that are all zeros)
This is very far from being enough information for the glmer() algorithm to come to a consensus. We can play around and resample the data to see what sort of size of data it would require for glmer() to be happy. This is of course not sound statistics, just for demonstration purposes.
set.seed(1)
tt2 <- rbind(tt, as.data.frame(lapply(tt, sample, 500, rep=TRUE)))
table(tt2)
# , , resp = 0
# 
#     expl
# pers  a  b  c  d d2  e e2  f  g  h  i
#   1   0  0  1  0  0  1  2  1  2  1  1
#   2   2  1  0  1  2  1  3  1  0  0  0
#   3   2  1  3  6  1  2  0  3  1  1  2
#   4   1  1  0  2  0  2  0  1  3  2  1
#   5   4  1  2  3  1  1  3  4  3  0  1
#   6   1  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  6  0  1
#   7   1  0  2  6  0  2  1  2  1  0  0
#   8   3  0  2  1  1  1  0  1  2  0  2
#   9   3  0  0  2  0  1  0  2  1  1  1
#   10  3  1  0  1  0  2  1  0  3  0  0
# 
# , , resp = 1
# 
#     expl
# pers  a  b  c  d d2  e e2  f  g  h  i
#   1   8  4  3  8  3  6  3  5  5  1  1
#   2   6  3  3  2  0  4  4  2  4  1  1
#   3   5  1  1  4  1  4  3  2  7  1  5
#   4  11  3  4  5  4  4  3  3  5  1  3
#   5  10  5  2  7  2  5  0  3  6  6  1
#   6   5  0  0  8  3  8  6  2  6  3  4
#   7   4  2  4  8  5  6  1  3 10  3  2
#   8   8  4  1  7  1  8  2  3  5  3  5
#   9   7  2  4  6  4  6  3  3  9  2  4
#   10  4  3  3  3  1  9  3  3  5  5  2
# 

library(lme4)
model <- glmer(resp~expl+(1|pers), data=tt2, family=binomial)

With 400 extra rows generated it still complained about singular fit, but with 500 it seems content.
While your model isn't particularly complex, the nature of your data (unbalanced, many levels in both explanatory and random variables) necessitates a lot more samples than what you have.

Very instructive! Thanks a lot!
